# Dired+ Not showing details anymore?

Tags: emacs, dired

I just updated to the most recent version of Dired+ and Emacs (from a nightly build) and, for some reason when I open Dired on any path, I don't see details (e.g. file size, permissions, size, etc.)

Has anything changed on Dired+ in the latest version? How do I restore the details view? Here is a snapshot of what I get now:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taken from the package documentation.

> Starting with Emacs 24.4 (I assume what you got in nightly), listing details are hidden by default.
>    Use `(` anytime to toggle this hiding.  You can use option
>    `diredp-hide-details-initially-flag` to change the default/initial
>    state.  See also option `diredp-hide-details-propagate-flag`.
>
> If you have an Emacs version older than 24.4, you can use library
>    `dired-details+.el` (plus `dired-details.el`) to get similar
>    behavior.

How to find it quickly: 
<kbd>M-x</kbd> find-library <kbd>enter</kbd> dired+<kbd>enter</kbd> <kbd>C-s</kbd> details

Comment: Updated comment in that file: If you do not want to hide details initially then you must either (1) change `diredp-hide-details-initially-flag` using Customize (recommended) or (2) set it to `nil` (e.g., using `setq`) **BEFORE** loading `dired+.el`.

Answer (score 4):

You can just press C-( to toggle it;